# Pandas Groupby using different agg methods for different columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here is the scenario:

- I have a large ordered dataset with 314 columns and over 300.000 lines for a ML problem.
- I wanna group by the dataset by column X (suppliers).
- One column is a datetime type, some columns are numeric by nature and
  others were one-hot encoded from some categorical columns.

Desired output:

- I wanna groupby column X, and aggregate the numeric columns by "mean", some columns by "last", and the one-hot-encoded ones by "sum". All on the same agg method.

Since we are talking about a 314 columns dataset I can't just create a dict containing each column.

```
df_train.groupby('Supplier').agg({<some columns> : 'last', <some columns>: 'sum', <some columns>: 'mean' })
```

PS: I ordered the columns using the sequence that I wanna apply the different aggregations.

Comment: perhaps you can use a dictionary comprehension to create your dictionary for the aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to get the columns that are numeric, and use these in a dictionary comprehension.

```
numeric_cols = df_train.select_dtypes('numeric').columns

agg_dict = {c: 'sum' if c in numeric_cols else 'last' for c in df_train.columns}

grouped = df_train.groupby('Supplier').agg(agg_dict)
```

With regards to your one-hot encoded columns, you will need to provide more information as to how they might be identified.

Comment: I'm trying to work among these lines. The problem is: the numeric by nature I wanna apply the "mean" and the one-hot-encoded ones (which are also numeric) I wanna apply "sum" :(

Comment: Can you keep track of the one-hot encoded columns as you encode them?

Comment: I'm considering a not-so-ellegant solution: grouping by into 3 different datasets using 3 different agg methods, then merge the desired columns afterwards.
Thanks, @asoungtoruin

Comment: how do you select your columns to encode? Can you make a list of them as you do it?

Comment: df_train.columns[1:7] should agg using "last"
df_train.columns[7:] should agg using "sum"

Comment: Which of those use mean though?

Comment: I decided not using the mean.